# JUnit not showing green tick for successful test on IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, junit

I am running test for this scala code using junit

```
//Scala Code
package com.sd.proj.executable

object HelloWorld {
  def my_message(msg:String):String ={
    msg
  }
}
```

```
//Scala Test
package com.sd.proj.junit_test

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatestplus.junit.JUnitRunner
import com.sd.proj.executable.HelloWorld
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.must.Matchers

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class HelloWorldTest extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers {
  val msg = HelloWorld.my_message("Hello World!!!")
  println("testing - " + msg)
  msg mustBe "Hello World!!!"
}
```

The test is executing correctly, however it does not show the green tick for the test, just shows this

[image]

this is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'scala'
    id 'idea'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets{
    main{
        scala.srcDirs = ['src/main/scala']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
    }
    test{
        scala.srcDirs = ['src/test/scala']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
    }
}

dependencies {
    //scala
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.15'
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.15'
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.15'
    //junit
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.scalatestplus:scalatestplus-junit_2.12:1.0.0-M2'
}
```

Intellij version - IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 (Community Edition)
OS : macOS ventura 13.0

This is the first time I am setting up IntelliJ to run code on my mac.
Can someone please suggest, is it something I am doing incorrectly or is this an issue with Intellij?

I was expecting a green tick for the passed test on intellij

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, found the solution.
I was writing the test incorrectly, it should be

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class HelloWorldTest extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers {
  "hello world" should "return" in {
    val msg = HelloWorld.my_message("Hello World!!!")
    println("testing - " + msg)
    msg mustBe "Hello World!!!"
  }
}
```